# Cannot roll back TRANSACTION. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2014

I have anonymous block

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION tran1
        -- insert query into table

        -- insert query into another table

    IF 1=2 -- false condition
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tran1;
    END

END
```

This transactions commits successfully. Then I change IF condition to be true  (`1=1`) and also change transaction name to `tran2`, so now anonymous block is:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION tran2
        -- insert query into table

        -- insert query into another table

    IF 1=1 -- true condition
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tran2;
    END

END
```

When trying run this block, it returns "query completed with errors" with message:

`Cannot roll back tran2. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.`

(also transaction not rollbacks and inserts are performed).

So, why appears that message when there is definitely transaction with name: "tran2" ?

Comment: "This transactions commits successfully." That seems improbable, given that there's no `COMMIT`, and ["when nesting transactions, `transaction_name` must be the name from the outermost `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181299) Are you sure the outermost transaction isn't simply still open?

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert -  `BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION tran1
   -- some insert query here, for example

 END;`

There is no commit at all, but this also commits successfully and insert happens

Comment: Check above and below your code, especially if you have some other nested BEGIN/END blocks. I can't replicate your error... see [here for example](http://rextester.com/LEK19874) though you'll have to run the code locally on your machine. I'm betting if your remove that outer begin/end block you'll start to figure out your issue

Comment: @OTARIKI: the insert is *visible* in the context of the transaction, but until you commit a transaction, it is *not* committed. To test this, check `@@TRANCOUNT`. If >0, you are still in a transaction and need a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` to end it.

Comment: Also (since this is a common misconception) `BEGIN`/`END` do nothing with transactions (they only group statements for syntactical purposes) and `BEGIN TRANSACTION` does not begin a block of statements and does not need to be paired with anything. The `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` can happen at any point in time after the `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, with no regards for statement nesting or scope at all.

Comment: Nested transactions are a myth. They do NOT do anything like what it seems like they should. They exist in name only, there is no functional feasibility of them at all. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert - Yes, `@@TRANCOUNT` gives 3.   `DBCC OPENTRAN` also gives that there is transaction with name: "tran1" alive. very confused, so when transactions not commits successfully, they are not "killed" by database?

Comment: Uncommitted transactions get rollbacked when the connection closes, or when a statement aborts the transaction (whether a failed statement aborts a transaction is subject to unintuitive rules). `BEGIN`/`END` blocks do nothing. If you're doing this in Management Studio, the connection won't close until you close the tab (at which point it will actually warn you that you have open transactions). Also, what Sean said: if you're giving your transactions names in the hope that you can roll them back in a nested way, you can't. Naming transactions is almost never useful.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Thank you, thanks very much all of you.